# Is it possible to retrieve the line number from an OleDbException caused by calling ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, exception

We are calling ExecuteNonQuery on all files in a certain folder for version scripting and if there is a syntax error an exception is raised. I have been scanning MSDN for a way to get the line number but haven't been able to find anything yet. There is a 'SqlException' class which does contain the line number but the shared base class 'DbException' does not contain this member.

Comment: Why are you using OleDb instead of SqlClient to work with SQL Server?

Comment: Suggest you make that an answer, Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` classes rather than `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` classes when accessing SQL Server.